# How many threads does Unary gRPC use?

Tags: grpc

I'm new to gRPC, and their documentation (for C#) is so annoying and outdated.

I'm trying to build a single threaded client/server application.
The server has an network API, where the client can execute some RPCs from the server's API (unary).

I don't understand how the server handles threading. I read that Unary gRPC can be sync or async.
Can I configure any of them to be single-threaded? If not, then is it possible to make the thread pool size 1?

Comment: In grpc-java, It uses netty server behind the scenes which actually follows the Non blocking IO Event loop model.

Comment: Does that mean it is single threaded by default?

Comment: Single or few number of threads based on your cpu core size.

Answer (score 0):

Threading and unary rpcs are two completely different pieces of the system.

Unary just means that you get back a single response and not a stream

I don't think it is possible to set the server thread pool to size 1 - that is the wrong use case for grpc- maybe you can use a mutex to lock every request so it executes sequentially

Or use something like vertx which can give you single threaded networked applications

Comment: Thanks. I really don't understand the design decision behind making a framework without being able to control how many threads your server is using. Do you have any idea why they did it like that?

Comment: Because it is made for high performance scenarios so netty takes care of threading for you - why are you using grpc? Why do you want it to be single threaded

Comment: I'm having a client/server app. A physical host might have multiple servers running, so I want to distribute the CPU cores among the servers.

Comment: Can you try setting this proeprty to 1 io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.eventLoopThreads

Answer (score 0):

For C#, I found the following to work.

GrpcEnvironment.SetThreadPoolSize(1);